# Setting k for KDTree search: chatgpt seems wrong

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kdtree

I have dataset consisting of 30 samples and 5 features.
I want kdtree search across all 30 samples and 5 features .
What should be the value for "k" parameter ?

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree

# Assuming your data is in a variable called 'data'
tree = KDTree(data)

# Query point
query_point = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]

# Find the 5 nearest neighbors
distances, indices = tree.query([query_point], k=5)

# 'indices' will contain the indices of the 5 nearest neighbors
# 'distances' will contain the distances to these neighbors
```

The chatgpt says that it should be 5.
But I do not think so.
Do someone know about it?

Comment: The choice of k (in `query`) is up to you and your problem, there isn't really a "should be".

Comment: @BenReiniger my question was: what k should be for "search across all 30 samples". I guess the answer is 30 then ?

Comment: No, "search across all 30 samples" doesn't imply anything about k. k is the number of results, the number of nearest neighbors, returned.  Maybe if would help to tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you meant you want the distance to all 30 points, then k=30 is what you want, but then there's no reason to use KDTree...

Answer (score 2):

The value for the "k" parameter in a KDTree search determines how many nearest neighbors you want to find for a given query point. In your code example, you are looking for the 5 nearest neighbors to the query_point.

So, if you want to find the 5 nearest neighbors, setting k=5 is the correct choice in this case. The code you provided will return the indices of the 5 nearest neighbors and their corresponding distances from the query_point.

Comment: I want kdtree search across all 30 samples and 5 features . What should be the value for "k" parameter ?

Comment: @mark 
"I want kdtree search across all 30 samples and 5 features" doesn't inform the choice of k (in `query`) at all. How many neighbors (from among the 30) do you want returned?

Comment: The sklearn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html) clearly says that k is "The number of nearest neighbors to return".  This answer is correct. Set k=5.

Comment: @BenReiniger So, k deals across samples only and it does not matter with #features ?

Comment: @JesseSealand My question was to search across all 30 samples. So, I think k should be 30 not 5. Is not it ?

Comment: K is not how many samples you want to search, kdtree will search all of the samples regardless. You just needs to tell it how many closest points you want. It will account for every sample.